# How to display them only once and 'total' for similar words using Angular7

Tags: angular, typescript

From this loop I get all Category of data.

`<mat-card-actions *ngFor="let item of category.Category?.split(',')" (click)="onFilterByCategory(item)"> <button mat-stroked-button color="primary">{{ item}}</button> </mat-card-actions>`

Show such as in [image]

I want to show

- Our Values (2)
- WIDE (2)
- Let me introduce (3)
- Art (1)
  etc

I want to display them only once and 'total' for similar words

Can you share with me any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.items = category.Category?.split(',').reduce((acc, item) => {
let value = acc[item] || 0;
return  {...acc, [item]: ++value};
}, {});

<mat-card-actions *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue" (click)="onFilterByCategory(item)">
 <button mat-stroked-button color="primary">{{item.key}}({{item.value})</button> </mat-card-actions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like this

component.ts

```
categories = ['cat1','cat2','cat3', 'cat2', 'cat1'];
result = {};

this.categories.forEach(i => {
  this.result[i] = this.categories.filter(item => item === i).length;
});
```

component.html

```
<mat-card-actions *ngFor="let item of categories" 
  (click)="onFilterByCategory(item)"> 
  <button mat-stroked-button color="primary">{{ item}}  {{result[item]}}</button> 
</mat-card-actions>
```

I just gave you the example of how you can display the count of repeated `categories`. You just have to create an object with each `category's count` with `category` `name` as `key` and value will be the count of the key.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use Map in this case

```
let categories = ["CatA", "CatB", "CatA", "CatC"]
this.categoriesMap = new Map<string, number>();
categories.forEach(category => {
  this.categoriesMap.set(category, (this.categoriesMap.get(category) || 0) + 1)
});
```

And then your html will be like below

```
<mat-card-actions *ngFor="let item of categoriesMap | keyvalue" 
  (click)="onFilterByCategory(item)"> 
  <button mat-stroked-button color="primary">{{ item.key}}  {{item.value}}</button> 
</mat-card-actions>
```